# If a foreign key does not exist, set the field to NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.main (
  [...]
  content TEXT NOT NULL,
  foreign_id INTEGER REFERENCES public.other(id)
);
```

I'm trying to do a particular insertion: if the insertion tries to put a `foreign_id` that doesn't exist in `public.other`, instead of having an foreign key exception, I'd like the field to be set to NULL automatically. Is this possible or I have to check the existence before?

Comment: You would need to use a trigger for this.  There is no other way to actually change the data that is being inserted.

Comment: This often ends badly because you have an application that "knows" that the data is in one state but the database reflects a different reality.